# How to map all language locales to one json file in angular translate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-translate

How to link all variants of English (Eg 'en-AS','en-BE') to one file 'en'(en.json)

```
.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(
            [
                'en_US',
                'de_DE'
            ], {
            'en_US' : 'en', 'en-AS': 'en', 'en-AU': 'en', 'en-BB': 'en', 'en-BE': 'en', 'en-BM': 'en', 'en-BW': 'en', 'en-BZ': 'en', 'en-CA': 'en', 'en-GB': 'en', 'en-GU': 'en', 'en-GY': 'en', 'en-HK': 'en', 'en-IE': 'en', 'en-IN': 'en', 'en-JM': 'en', 'en-MH': 'en', 'en-MP': 'en', 'en-MT': 'en', 'en-MU': 'en', 'en-NA': 'en', 'en-NZ': 'en', 'en-PH': 'en', 'en-PK': 'en', 'en-SG': 'en', 'en-TT': 'en', 'en-UM': 'en', 'en-US': 'en', 'en-US-POSIX': 'en', 'en-VI': 'en', 'en-ZA': 'en', 'en-ZW': 'en',
            'de_DE' : 'de', 'de_AT': 'de', 'de_BE': 'de', 'de_CH': 'de', 'de_DE': 'de', 'de_LI': 'de', 'de_LU': 'de'
        })
```

I have attached a plunker link
http://embed.plnkr.co/TP9WmO/

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer for mapping all variants of same language to one file

```
.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['es', 'en','pt','fr','de','ja','it', ], {
                    'en-*':'en', 
                    'es-*':'es', 
                    'pt-*':'pt',
                    'fr-*':'fr',
                    'de-*':'de',
                    'ja-*':'ja',
                    'it-*':'it'
                    })
```